# Error can't change name BulkyWeb to BulkyBookWeb because Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo0Ct.png)

I got this error when changing the name `BulkyWeb` to `BulkyBookWeb`. I can't rename - why? By the way it is the code from Mr Patel for building an e-commerce website. Any help will be appreciated - thank you.

`BulkyWeb` needs to be renamed to `BulkyBookWeb`. How to do this? I can't make this change because I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)